# How to integrate react-native-text-detector successfully?

Tags: xcode, react-native

The documentation for this library's install has been followed step for step.

- `npm install react-native-text-detector --save`
- added `pod "RNTextDetector", path: '../node_modules/react-native-text-detector/ios` to pod file
- did *not* manually link binary or add file to library in Xcode

However the build continually fails. it fails in the same way when trying to integrate `react-native-tesseract-ocr`, one of the dependencies for this library.

the build error:

`-weak_library and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem...

After some more research, I looked into a few things regarding tesseract-ocr for iOS that helped get everything up and running as expected.

1. Install react-native-text-detector per the repo's README
2. Added the linker flag -lstdc++ in Xcode build settings
3. Set the build setting Enable Bitcode to NO in Xcode build settings
4. Followed the README in this repo, https://github.com/Kila2/libstdc-.6.0.9.tbd/blob/master/README.md

After that I was able to build and run both on the iOS simulator and on a test device.

Comment: I tried to follow the readme file you listed but I couldn't figure out where to add thedylib file because I don't have this path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/".  Every time I try to run my simulator it just locks up on startup, a blank screen.  If I roll back the tesseract import all works fine.

Comment: @Razir66 which version of Xcode do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

I have 11.3, the latest stable version.